# How large should a hashtable be initialized related to the entries count?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hashtable

Is there an optimal size for a hashtable related to the entry count?

So for entries = `n` is there an optimal (or recommended) size `s` for the hashtable which depends on `n`? Lets say `2n` (double the entries count) or some other value?

Is it depending on the internal structure (hash function, bucket size, etc.)? Please provide some evidence when claiming something.

Comment: I was taught (years ago) that *s* should be of size at least the next prime number greater than *n*. There's a good discussion at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ratio between the size of the table and the number of entries is called the [load factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_factor_%28computer_science%29#Load_factor) of a hash table.

The load factor crucially determines the expected runtime behaviour. For the usual bounds (i.e. expected time O(1) on all operations) to apply, it has to be smaller than 1.

In practice, the remark by Pete Wilson applies: one tries to keep the load factor close to 1 in order not to waste space; a prime number size for the table is often used to improve the collision characteristics of the hash function – but other strategies exist.

Comment: So choosing a size of `1.5n` should be generally fine, if I don't expect it to grow.

Comment: This answer is correct, but I found it somewhat frustrating. The load factor describes the ratio of entries to available buckets. So of course "one tries" to keep the load factor close to 1, since that is the whole purpose of hashing - and therefore tells us nothing whatsoever regarding the initial question. As I understand it, the "optimal size" is determined as the relation between how much memory is required and how often collisions occur. Using more memory should reduce collisions but may waste space.

Comment: So the question is: how many entries are likely for the use context on average, and how many collisions are likely for that number of entries (of the specific type(s) anticipated by the hash method)?

Comment: @Asher Quite right. But often in performance-critical applications you have a pretty good idea of how many entries you’ll need.

Answer (score 2):

In java, with class HashTable, the default load factor (.75) offers a good tradeoff between time and space costs.

A higher load factor value decreases the space requirements and increases the odds of a collision. A collision increases the amount of time needed to perform a get() and put(...).

A lower load factor value increases disk/memory space requirements, causing lots of reserved space that is permanently unused.  The increased number of bins decreases the odds of a collision.

So a load factor of (.75) means the HashTable bins are 75% full.  If you have 75 elements to store, the number of bins in your HashTable should be 100.

Therefore, answering your question, given N as the number of items to store in your HashTable, the size of your HashTable should be about (1.33 * n).  Other circumstances may make different load factors faster in some situations.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html